# How to access a specific taxonomy in the page template?

Tags: tera, zola

I am trying to render the index.html with each entry listing the tags for each post.

_index.md:

```
---
title = "Posts"
sort_by = "date"
template = "posts/index.html"
page_template = "posts/page.html"
---
```

Example post:

```
taxonomies:
  tags:
    - aws
    - lambda
    - bun
```

posts/index.html:

```html
{% if page.taxonomies.tags %}
   {{ post.taxonomies.tags | json_encode }}
{% else %}
   {{ [] | json_encode }}
{% endif %}
```

Rendering index.html results in [] for all posts even though the taxonomy is enabled in config.toml. Is there anything else to configure to get the tags accessible for posts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the post page first, then iterate over its tags:

```
{% set post_page = get_page(path=“posts/first/index.md”) %}
{% for tag in post_page.taxonomies.tags %}
  {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```